# How do disable the Format field in the dialogue wdDialogFileSaveAs in C #, I'm working on a draft Office add-in?

Tags: c#, excel, dialog, ms-word, ms-office

I'm programming an extension for Microsoft Office 2010 and 2013, which involve saving the current document to PDF. Currently, I have the following code.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Dialog DialogBox = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Dialogs[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFileSaveAs];

System.Type DialogType = typeof(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Dialog);
object oDlg = (object)DialogBox;

object[] oArgs2 = new object[1];
oArgs2[0] = (object)@"Documento.pdf";
oDlg.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, oDlg, oArgs2);

object[] oArgs = new object[1];
oArgs[0] = (object)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;
oDlg.GetType().InvokeMember("Format", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, oDlg, oArgs);
object timeOut = null;

int result = DialogBox.Show(ref timeOut);
```

This shows the native File Save Dialog of Microsoft Office. It also sets the default save format to PDF. However, I need to guarantee that the file is saved in PDF format.

Is there a way to restrict the File Save Dialog to only show the PDF format option and remove/hide all the rest?